# Не работает простейший код на React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

у меня не работает простейший код на React.js
Очень хотелось бы понять что именно не так, любая помощь - полезна. Заранее большое спасибо)

Код:

```
import './style/App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

    const[prisvoenie, setPrisvoenie] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          setPrisvoenie(res);
        })
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {prisvoenie}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная prisvoenie является объектом (после запроса станет массивом), а реакт не разрешает рендерить объекты, вам нужно сделать prisvoenie.map() и возвращать из него разметку

```
import './style/App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

    const[prisvoenie, setPrisvoenie] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          setPrisvoenie(res);
        })
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {prisvoenie.map(el => {
        return <тут ваш код>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```